# PInvoke not working in class definition

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a problem, strange one. 
When I am using with the next struct in PInvoke it is working but when I change it to class it is not working.

my c# :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SPInvokeImage
{          
    public int m_BitsPerPixel;  // 8,16,24,32 
    public int m_ImageHeight;
    public int m_ImageWidth;
    public int m_BytesArraySize; // array size in bytes. 

    public IntPtr m_pArray; //data array 
}
```

c++

```
   typedef struct 
   {          
 int mBitsPerPixel;  // 8,16,24,32 
 int mImageHeight;
 int mImageWidth;
 int BytesArraySize; // array size in bytes. 

 uint8_t *Array;        //data array 
   }SPInvokeImage;
```

when I change the c# to be like this it stops working:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 public class SPInvokeImage
 {          
     public int m_BitsPerPixel;  // 8,16,24,32 
     public int m_ImageHeight;
     public int m_ImageWidth;
     public int m_BytesArraySize; // array size in bytes. 

     public IntPtr m_pArray; //data array 
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the StructLayout attribute?

Comment: Why do you want using a class if a working with a struct ?

Comment: because as i know struct can't be move like null pointer

Comment: How are you using the class/struct? What is your exact error?

Comment: Use then nullable/? with the struct instead.

Comment: The code is working and compile but the data that arived to the c++ is garbage

Comment: You cannot pass nullable types to P/Invoke without a lot of work that is absolutely not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

It's because when you switch to a class, the object is passed to the native code by reference rather than by value as it is for a `struct`. So there is an extra level of indirection. You'll need to remove that level of indirection in your pinvoke declaration. You are probably passing using `ref` at the moment. Simply remove the `ref` when you switch from `struct` to `class`.

Answer (score 2):

Structs are value types, while classes are reference types. The rules for how those two types are passed into a P/Invoke method call are different.

Is there a particular reason you want to use a class when a struct is working fine? You clearly want value-type semantics, so use a value type to get them.

If you truly need to make it a class for some reason, I'd need to see the method signature you're calling to see what is going wrong. Most likely you have a `ref` tacked on somewhere it doesn't belong.

EDIT: Based on your comment about null pointers:

Using a class here is one option, just make sure you don't pass it explicitly by `ref`, since that happens automatically. Another option is to use an `IntPtr` and pass either `IntPtr.Zero` for a null value, or the result of [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx) for a real value.

Comment: It's not uncommon to use `class` in these situations.

Comment: True, but the IntPtr technique also works for primitive value types like int that need to be "nullable", so it's good to know how to do both :)

Comment: Yeah, lots of ways to skin this. Can Marshal.StructureToPtr be used with int. I had not actually thought about that ever.

Comment: I don't *think* so; it takes an object, so I assume you'd get a reference to a boxed int if you tried. That sounds like a road to disaster :)

Comment: That seems to contradict your earlier statement: the IntPtr technique also works for primitive value types like int that need to be "nullable"

Comment: If you wanted to pass a structure you use Marshal.StructureToPtr; if you want to pass a primitive type you would use Marshal.WriteInt32. In either case, IntPtr.Zero would represent null.

Comment: Well, you could do that I suppose. But why would you prefer AllocHGlobal, WriteInt32, FreeHGlobal to a simple pass by `ref` or `out`?

Comment: Because a `ref` or `out` int cannot be passed as null, while an `int *` in C can; there's no other way to pass an "optional writable int" without overloading the C# function.